# Present Value Cash Flow Questions - Discounting

Tags: finance, actuarial-science

> At an annual effective interest rate of i, i > 0 all the following are equal:
>
> i. the present value of 10,000 at the end of 6 years
>
> ii.    the sum of the present values of 6000 at the end of year t and 56,000 at the end of year 2t
>
> iii.   5000 immediately
>
> Calculate $v^t$.

Note the following equations:

$FV= PV(1+i)^t\tag{1}$

or we can express this in terms of present value:

$PV=\cfrac{FV}{(1+i)^t}=FV \cdot v^t\tag{2}$

Where $v^t$ is known as the present value factor.  From the three equations, I wrote the following:

$10,000 v^6=6,000v^t + 56,000 v^{2t}=5000\tag{3}$

So we have a systems of equations and I broke it down to solve for $v$:

$10,000 v^6 = 5000 \implies v=\left(\cfrac{5}{10}\right)^{1/6}=0.891\tag{4}$

Now I used the second part of the equation:

$6,000v^t + 56,000 v^{2t}=5000$

$v^t ( 6 + 56 v^2) = 5 \implies v^t= \cfrac{5}{6+56 v^2}=\cfrac{5}{6+56 (0.891)^2} \approx 0.1$

So I got 0.1 but the answer is 0.25.  Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your factoring is off - pls note $v^t \cdot v^2 = v^{2+t}$ and not $v^{2t}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x = v^t$.  From $56 v^{2t} + 6v^t = 5$, we have $56x^2 + 6x - 5 = 0$.

If you recall the quadratic formula, you should get one positive root, which is exactly what you need.